# Is there any way you can update a project without reinstalling it?

Tags: mean.io

Well, just what I said. So, they recently fixed the security issue with the login through facebook and twitter and stuff, but, in my version, that stuff is still broken. Is there anyway I can update the project? Or do I just have to create a whole new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> git pull upstream master && npm install

Check here for more info
https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1012